# Why am I getting Cannot read property 'style' of null when trying to change div style by id?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I have read similar questions regarding this error but still couldn't debug my situation.

I need one part of my program to change some html (mainly show and hide less or more inputs) depending on what the user selects.

I am using `document.getElemenyById().style.display ="block"` and `"none"` to change that property of the divs in the html file but one of them gets the error referring to its style property being null.

I can't figure out why, as it seems to me to have no difference with the one above it:
`id="opcionesdeMandamiento"` works fine showing and hiding, but `document.getElementById("opcionesdeInhibición").style.display = "block"` gets *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.*

I will cut most of the original input options to make it more readable, basically they are just a bunch of select tags, text and numbers fields and checkboxes.

HTML

```
 <!-- MEDIDAS CAUTELARES -->
<select id="cautelar" onchange="selecciondeCautelar()">
   <option value="default">Seleccionar Medida Cautelar</option>
   <option value="mandamiento">Mandamiento</option>
   <option value="inhibición">Inhibición General</option>
</select>



<!-- OPCIONES DE MANDAMIENTO-->
<div id="opcionesdeMandamiento" style="display:none">
<label>Ley:
<select>
  <option value="Local">Local</option>
  <option value="3.556">3.556</option>
  <option value="22.172>">22.172</option>
</label><br>
</div>

<!-- OPCIONES DE INHIBICIÓN-->
<div id="opcionesdeInhibición" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

JS

```
//Selección de medida Cautelar
function selecciondeCautelar() {
  switch (document.getElementById("cautelar").value) {
  case "mandamiento": //show opcionesdeMandamiento
  document.getElementById("opcionesdeMandamiento").style.display = "block";
  break;
  case "inhibición": //show opcionesdeInhibición
  document.getElementById("opcionesdeMandamiento").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("opcionesdeInhibición").style.display = "block";
  break;
}
}
```

**document.getElementById("opcionesdeInhibición").style.display = "block";**

This line is the one that cannot be executed;
I have already tried placing the script inside the html body, in a different file as well as trying to get its value through the console with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It *shouldn't* make any difference, but have you tried changing `opcionesdeInhibición` to `opcionesdeInhibicion` (i.e. only using basic ascii characters)?

Comment: _It shouldn't make any difference_  = that's it. answer is down.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was typo error, you didin't close html `</select>` see my example:

```js
function selecciondeCautelar() {

  switch (document.getElementById("cautelar").value) {
  case "mandamiento": //show opcionesdeMandamiento
  document.getElementById("opcionesdeMandamiento").style.display = "block";
  break;
  case "inhibición": //show opcionesdeInhibición
  document.getElementById("opcionesdeMandamiento").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("opcionesdeInhibición").style.display = "block";
  break;
}
}
```

```html
<!-- MEDIDAS CAUTELARES -->
<select id="cautelar" onchange="selecciondeCautelar(this)">
   <option value="default">Seleccionar Medida Cautelar</option>
   <option value="mandamiento">Mandamiento</option>
   <option value="inhibición">Inhibición General</option>
</select>



<!-- OPCIONES DE MANDAMIENTO-->
<div id="opcionesdeMandamiento" style="display:none">
<label>Ley:</label>
<select>
  <option value="Local">Local</option>
  <option value="3.556">3.556</option>
  <option value="22.172>">22.172</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<!-- OPCIONES DE INHIBICIÓN-->
<div id="opcionesdeInhibición" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

i suggest you to use `this` on inline call function and use it on your function like :

```
function selecciondeCautelar(el) {

  switch (el.value) {
```

Another tips use variable for the two `div` because you need to use always.

Comment: Hello, YES, this was it. Thanks a lot, and it explained some other behaviours.

Comment: can you acept my question ? :)

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: @Quentin the question has a clear error message which would be findable with google, so I'm not convinced this is clearly trivial or unlikely to help future users.

Comment: My bad so, i add tips to but if you confirm i will delete it

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your feedback, specially to @Simone Rossaini,